# How do I detect if a bytearray is empty in python?

Tags: python

I need to detect when the bytearray is empty like these two in the middle: [image: 6 bytearrays 2 empty]

I am quite new to coding so I have tried this, but it doesnt detect when its for a bytearray:

```
 if my_bytearray == "":
     print("Read drop out")
```

Comment: `if not my_bytearray:` should work fine.

Comment: if not my_bytearray: print('empty")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not my_bytearray:
    print("Read drop out")
```

should work fine.

The mistake in your code is that you compare a bytearray to a string; that is always `False`. `if my_bytearray == b"":` would have worked. But the solution above tends to be more Pythonic and more used.